# Exception handling - Try Catch ambiguous behaviour (??)

Tags: exception, apache-camel

This is My code

```
from("direct:test-POST")
        .doTry()
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                throw new NullPointerException(" Null value");

            }
        })
        .doCatch(NullPointerException.class)
        .log("${exception}") // This Prints NullPointer Exception
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println( arg0.getException() ); //This prints Null

            }
        })
        .end();
```

Am using **jetty:run** to run this camel route.

How do I catch the exception. It prints the exception correct in log. but inside the processor, the exception is null. what am I missing

Answer (score 4):

I would think the exception is found on a property on the exchange. Something like:

```
Throwable caused = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, NullPointerException.class);
assertNotNull(caused);
```

Comment: Correct. The doTry/doCatch marks the Exception as handled and then it is the same behavior like you can see here: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html